# Проблема с self,instance в Python Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, kivy

Код:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random

r,g,b,a = 0,0,0,0
pos_vari = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]
pos_vari_a = [1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2]
r_pnt = 0
class ColorApp(App):

    def changeColor(self, instance):

        global r,g,b,a,pos_vari,pos_vari_a,rp


        r = random.choice(pos_vari)
        g = random.choice(pos_vari)

        b = random.choice(pos_vari)

        a = random.choice(pos_vari_a)
        instance.background_color = [r,g,b,a]
        mix = "RGB:"+" "+ str(r)+" | " +str(g) + " | " +str(b)
        instance.font_size = 120
        instance.text = mix

    def rf(self,instance):

        self.changeColor(instance.background_color)

    def build(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        colorButton = Button(text="ColorS",font_size=250, background_color=[1,1,1,1],on_press=self.changeColor)
        bl.add_widget(colorButton)
        bl_st = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1,0.1))

        rup = Button (text="Up R",on_press=self.rf)
        gup = Button (text="Up G")
        bup = Button (text="Up B")
        bl_st.add_widget(rup)
        bl_st.add_widget(gup)
        bl_st.add_widget(bup)
        bl.add_widget(bl_st)
        return bl


ColorApp().run()
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы при  нажатии на r.up,g.up,b up увеличивалось значение r/g/b на background главной кнопки на 0.1,но все время вылетают ошибки.(self.changeColor(instance.background_color) )

Например,Когда добавляю              self.changeColor(instance.background_color) = [r+0.1,g,b,a]

Выдает:SyntaxError,can't assign to function call

Comment: @jfs добавил ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Питоне, результат вызова функции не может быть целевым объектом [присваивания](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). Поэтому вы получаете SyntaxError.

В общем случае (не только в kivy коде) вы можете изменить интерфейс метода, чтобы он новый цвет принимал и превратить в свойство:

```
@property
def background_color(self):
    return "get color here"

@background_color.setter
def background_color(self, color):
    "set color here"
```

Тогда вызов можно заменить на присваивание свойству:

```
self.background_color = r, g, b, a
```

В случае с кнопкой уже есть атрибут `background_color`, поэтому не нужно `@property` определять, а можно напрямую атрибут у кнопки выставлять:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

RED = [1, 0, 0, 1]
GREEN = [0, 1, 0, 1]

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton@Button>:
   color: 0, 0, 0, 1
   background_normal: ''
   text: 'Change color'
''')


class MyButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        if self.background_color == GREEN:
            self.background_color = RED
        else:
            self.background_color = GREEN


class ColorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyButton()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ColorApp().run()
```

Сложнее пример, который ближе к коду в вопросе, который увеличивает цветовые компоненты при нажатии на соответствующие кнопки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
#:set BGCOLOR 0,0,0,1
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: button
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: BGCOLOR
        color: .5,.5,.5,1
        text: 'color: ' + str(button.background_color)
        on_press: button.background_color = BGCOLOR  # reset
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,.1
        Button:
            text: 'R'
            on_press: button.background_color[0] += .1
        Button:
            text: 'G'
            on_press: button.background_color[1] += .1
        Button:
            text: 'B'
            on_press: button.background_color[2] += .1
''')


class ColorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ColorApp().run()
```

Comment: ,никак не могу найти правильное место этому коду,можете пояснить куда вставлять, пожалуйста.

Comment: Выдает море раз self.background_color = r,g,b,a.А потом RunTimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @QqqqSsss подумайте к какой ошибке ведёт `f = lambda: f(); f()` код и почему. Если не ясно, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, специально об этом.

Comment: Пожалуйста,можете указать место вставки.Уже задаю очень много отдельных вопросов,а проблема так и не уходит,прошу.

Comment: @QqqqSsss: добавил полный пример кода, в котором цвет кнопки меняется по нажатию

Comment: @jfs Так я уже сделал чтобы цвет меняла при клике,я хотел чтобы кнопки up r,up g,up b при нажатии на них увеличивали значение r,g,b соответственно на background'е и цвет менялся тоже на r,g или b

Comment: @QqqqSsss замените `с=...` на `с[0]+=1` (для red) и будет увеличивать вместо присваивания.

Comment: @jfs Спасибо большое

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97948/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs---self-instance--python-kivy).